# How to use socket.io when you're using a views directory

Tags: node.js, socket.io, ejs

Here's all the code I'm using to try create a chat service. However, I can't seem to get my io.connection up and running since my file directory is different to a standard one used in documentation.

Here's my directory :
|-- index.js
|-- routes/
|-- index.js
|-- views/
|-- index.html
|-- chat.html
|-- public/
|-- js/
|-- chat.js

Index.js file

```
const express = require("express");
const app = express();
const http = require("http");
const server = http.createServer(app);
const { Server } = require("socket.io");
const io = new Server(server);

app.set("view engine", "ejs");
app.set("views", "views");

app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, "public")));

app.use("/", mainRoutes);

io.on("connection", (socket) => {
  console.log("New WebSocket connection");
});

app.listen(3000, () => {
  console.log(`Server Started at ${3000}`);
});
```

Views/main/index file :

```
    <h1>Join a Chat Room</h1>
    <form action="/main/join-room" method="POST">
      <input type="text" name="room" placeholder="Room Name" required />
      <button type="submit">Join Room</button>
    </form>
    <script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
    <script src="/js/main.js"></script>
  </body>
```

views/main/chat file :

```
  <body>
    <ul id="messages"></ul>
    <form id="messageForm">
      <input
        id="messageInput"
        autocomplete="off"
        placeholder="Type a message..."
        required
      />
      <button type="submit">Send</button>
    </form>

    <script>
      const socket = io();

      document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () => {
        socket.emit("joinRoom", { room: roomName });

        document
          .getElementById("messageForm")
          .addEventListener("submit", function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            let message = document.getElementById("messageInput").value;
            socket.emit("chatMessage", { room: roomName, message: message });
            document.getElementById("messageInput").value = ""; // Clear input after sending
          });

        socket.on("message", function (msg) {
          let li = document.createElement("li");
          li.textContent = msg;
          document.getElementById("messages").appendChild(li);
        });
      });
    </script>
    <script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
    <script src="/js/main.js"></script>
  </body>
```

public/js/main.js file :

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () => {
  const socket = io(); // Connect to the server

  // Extract room name from the URL or a hidden input field
  // Assuming you're passing the room name in a query string or within a hidden input field in your HTML
  const urlParams = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search);
  const room =
    urlParams.get("room") || document.getElementById("roomName").value;

  if (room) {
    socket.emit("joinRoom", { room }); // Join the specified room
  }

  socket.on("message", (message) => {
    console.log("Message from server:", message);
  });

  // Listen for messages from the server
  socket.on("message", (message) => {
    displayMessage(message);
  });

  // Send a message to the server
  const messageForm = document.getElementById("messageForm");
  if (messageForm) {
    messageForm.addEventListener("submit", (e) => {
      e.preventDefault();
      const messageInput = document.getElementById("messageInput");
      const message = messageInput.value;
      console.log(message);
      socket.emit("chatMessage", { room, message }); // Emit the message along with the room name
      messageInput.value = ""; // Clear the input field
    });
  }

  // Function to append messages to the DOM
  function displayMessage(message) {
    console.log(message);
    const messagesList = document.getElementById("messages");
    const messageElement = document.createElement("li");
    messageElement.textContent = message.text; // Assuming the message object has a text property
    messagesList.appendChild(messageElement);
    messagesList.scrollTop = messagesList.scrollHeight; // Auto-scroll to the latest message
  }
});
```